# If $F: E \to E'$ is an isomorphism of vector bundles, how can I show the restriction to each fiber $F_p : E_p \to E'_p$ is a linear isomorphism?

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles

> If $F: E \to E'$ is an isomorphism of vector bundles, how can I show the restriction to each fiber $F_p : E_p \to E'_p$ is a linear isomorphism?

Since $F$ is a isomorphism of vector bundles, it is a homeomorphism.

I'm having trouble showing $F_p$ is bijective. I know $F_p$ is linear, but I don't see a reason why this must automatically be bijective.

I tried using the local trivialization $E_p, E'_p \cong \{p\} \times \mathbb R^k$, but no luck.

Comment: Isn’t it by definition ?

Comment: @Sou No. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle#Vector_bundle_morphisms

Comment: IIRC this is true of coherent sheaves (of which vector bundles are a motivating example), so you can probably get away with only showing that the fiber map is injective. That should follow by looking at sufficiently small neighborhoods around the fiber.

Comment: I think it is straightforward from definition since its inverse is also bundle homomorphism.

Comment: @Sou We know $F$ is a homeomorphism, but why should that imply $F_p$ is bijective? How do we know $F_p$ takes $E_p$ onto $E'_p$? In other words, how do we know the codomain $E'_p$ is actually the range?

Comment: If $f_p$ is not bijective, which can only happen by saying that $f_p$ is not surjective, then there would be another element outside $E_p$ that is mapped to $E_{f(p)}$ which is forbidden since by definition f carries fibers to fibers.

Comment: Fibers over a given fixed point is a functor from vector bundles over a fixed base space to vector spaces. Isomorphisms map to isomorphisms under a functor. Sou is correct.

Comment: The codomain of $F_p$ is not necessarily $E’_p$. It’s $F_p : E_p \rightarrow E_{F(p)}’$.

Comment: @Sou $F(p)$ does not make sense: $p$ is in the base space, not in $E$.

Comment: Sorry i made a few mistakes so its not fit into your context but it really is straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment.

We can do this twice in two different contexts.

**Your apparent context:** It appears you are considering the category of (cts/smooth/etc) vector bundles over a fixed base. In this category bundle maps from $E$ to $E'$ are (cts/smooth/etc) maps 
$F:E\to E'$ such that $\pi' F = \pi$, where $\pi:E\to B$ and $\pi': E'\to B$ are the projections.

Then if $p\in B$, and $x\in E_p = \pi^{-1}(p)$, then $\pi'(F(x)) = \pi(x)=p$. Thus $F(x)\in E'_p$. Therefore, we can see that for each $p\in B$, we have a functor 
$E\mapsto E_p$ from vector bundles over $B$ to vector spaces. Since functors take isomorphisms to isomorphisms, an isomorphism $\phi:E\to E'$ induces an isomorphism between $E_p$ and $E'_p$.

Now we can generalize.

**The general case:** Consider the category consisting of 
pairs $(E,B,\pi,b)$ with $E$ a vector bundle over $B$, $\pi:E\to B$ the projection, and $b\in B$ a point.

Morphisms from $(E,B,\pi,b)$ to $(E',B',\pi',b')$ are bundle maps 
$(F,f)$ with $F:E\to E'$, $f:B\to B'$ such that $f(b)=b'$, and the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
E @>F>> E' \\
@V\pi VV @VV\pi' V\\
B @>f>> B' 
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.

Now we have a functor which sends the object 
$(E,B,\pi,b)$ to $E_b := \pi^{-1}(b)$.
Checking that a morphism $(F,f)$ sends $E_b$ to $E'_{b'}$ is the same as in the earlier case.